# List SQL Server role members

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to list specific users having server role 'sysadmin' or 'securityadmin'.

My goal is to get:

```
name    role       type_description   is_disabled
-------------------------------------------------
User1   sysadmin   windows_group         0
```

I have 2 issues:

1. I failed to show the role name 2
2. The instance is case sensitive and `DOM\MSSQL_Admins` will be displayed (and it shouldn't be)

This is my code:

```
SELECT   
    name, type_desc, is_disabled
FROM     
    master.sys.server_principals 
WHERE    
    (IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin', name) = 1
     OR IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('securityadmin', name) = 1)
    AND name NOT IN ('sa', LOWER('dom\mssql_admins'), 'dom\netbackup_mssql', 'dom\userX',
                     'NT SERVICE\SQLWriter', 'NT SERVICE\Winmgmt',
                     'NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER',
                     'NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT', 'dom\SQL-TASK')
    AND name NOT LIKE '%$%'
ORDER BY 
    name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `sys.server_role_members` table and the `sys.server_principals` table to get the desired information :

```
SELECT
    p.name AS [name],
    r.name AS [role],
    p.type_desc AS [type_description],
    p.is_disabled
FROM
    sys.server_role_members m
    INNER JOIN sys.server_principals p ON m.member_principal_id = p.principal_id
    INNER JOIN sys.server_principals r ON m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
WHERE
    (
        r.name = 'sysadmin'
        OR r.name = 'securityadmin'
    )
    AND (
        LOWER(p.name) NOT IN (
            'sa',
            LOWER('dom\mssql_admins'),
            LOWER('dom\netbackup_mssql'),
            LOWER('dom\userX'),
            'NT SERVICE\SQLWriter',
            'NT SERVICE\Winmgmt',
            'NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER',
            'NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT',
            LOWER('dom\SQL-TASK')
        )
        OR p.name = 'DOM\MSSQL_Admins'
    )
    AND p.name NOT LIKE '%$%'
ORDER BY
    p.name;
```

The `sys.server_role_members` table is joined with `sys.server_principals` twice: once to get the principal member information (`p`) and once to get the principal role information (`r`).

Comment: thanks, it works fine! But still there is a problem with "lower" and "upper", 'dom\mssql_admins' appears and it shouldn't.
my idea with: lower('dom\mssql_admins') doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share your input and expected output ?

Comment: I'm using your script with the slight modification:

    AND p.name NOT IN (
        'sa',  lower('DOM\MSSQL_ADMINS'),......


and still get the output:

DOM\MSSQL_Admins sysadmin WINDOWS_GROUP 0

sorry, I'm struggling with the formatting

Comment: @Purclot Instead of using functions, use `COLLATE` to a case-insensitive collation